# Trying to set up Slick and LWJGL in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, lwjgl

I'm trying to run a test file for both Slick and LWJGL and I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:73)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66)
at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:95)
at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:112)
at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:132)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer$1.run(AppGameContainer.java:39)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.<clinit>(AppGameContainer.java:36)
at SimpleTest.main(SimpleTest.java:28)
```

I know that I have set the native files for lwjgl.jar to point to the folders containing the dll files as shown below.

[image]
Also the lwjgl.jar and slick.jar are already part of the referenced libraries.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I my self have experienced the same problems, the solution was to downgrade to Eclipse Juno if you're using the new Kepler version. Or, try deleting the current project and then re-import it, resetting everything up.

Other guesses that might work, put all the natives and external Libraries in a concentrated separate folder outside the project and set it up from there.

Answer (score 0):

The error occurs because the corresponding `dll` library is not found in any location specified by the `java.library.path` system property.

In Eclipse the easiest way to make your native library available is to do the following:

1. Right-click at your project and go to `Java Build Path` -> `Libraries` tab.
2. Expand your `lwjgl.jar` node.
3. Select the `Native library location` attribute and choose "Edit". Make that point to your `lib` folder.

I hope it helps